# How to clean captured text fields in python within google app engine and webapp

Tags: google-app-engine, validation, web-applications

My question is: How can I clean captured text fields (e.g. emails) to ensure that they are valid entries and not malicious scripts.

I'm am just getting to grips with developing with google app engine using their webapp framework and python. I have a bunch of text fields within a few pages which I would like to clean. By cleaning I mean to remove all suspicious characters e.g. underscores _ a la django clean().

I have done some reading about using form frameworks however my forms include jquery elements which need to be independently rendered so I cannot see how to use them.

Cheers,
J

Comment: An email address with an underscore in it is *suspicious*?

Answer (score 0):

Form libraries like Django's are the standard way to validate forms. If you need to generate your form yourself, you can do so - Django and others provide ways to insert the relevant bits inside your own hand-written form and still handle validation correctly. See [the docs](http://django096docs.appspot.com/newforms.html) for details.

Form libraries won't perform escaping for you, however. You should do that on output, instead - templating libraries (again, like Django's) have built in support for this). If you're doing something internally that would require escaping, such as interpolating user input into a GQL query, that's usually a code smell indicating you should be doing something else - in the case of the GQL query, use parameter substitution.

Also note that email validation is extremely hard to do properly. About all you can safely do is check if it has an `@` symbol in it, and validate it by attempting to send an email to it.